# Inserting signal into Vega data with `trigger`, being flat mapped

Tags: vega

I was trying to store a brush interaction (signal) into a data via a trigger. However, the tuple seems to be flattened---I was expecting it to be `[[brush_start, brush_end], [brush_start, brush_end],...]`, but now it's just `[brush_start, brush_end, brush_start, brush_end...]]`.
[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0AQUVwkAAlhJFmCHrYAzPRExsoAaz05lUBVL0B3OjD1JxemuKYcIpIUGqkZqSKxDRw7j7isnrmNAA2QTpJ8phIaXoxcRCU0iCesvRoAOwATAAMMvA0ZFhoACwAHPUgOEiysgFkaAIyEE3iSKkQaADaoOMIcGhycDlpACJsyAEgAL4AujKySDkzc0gLSxA4ArW1JQyKqUtHOZzXt5RQEMQl5myKyEwaFAmAAnjhFugvj8ZD1FBBIaAnDQXEtxAwEExgiUXpC5MdFjsiVIzhd0AjUnAwnBZCUJKcQJhlGQyNj0NlcqkNltJDIAgjjM8VpzublJPt9jJkIo7FNULNGeC8WRFGwGDgSvM8Ry0iU4OIoGx5MCQPqMibGs0gahQMQJgxIQBmACctR2MjKFRtIDtqQdVTqRPdIGgEwUDK1SwAHmthbqZGCIUs1BcZCFxKylp6YDjNmKTS8UOT3ncZCk4KlaeyCbtDnmAgAlJDuE2jMjjJ7suNc+vi92kvGg2OrJ4JpVLVIBXSKErpzPyl31WoHOS9gvHIshku-WKVpbI1HB8QoyFMh0yABewTYaDPcElICQUfD8tA-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-wk-DADUejyJzbjizAksAIwy3LFY5Acei09mj3If2ICzY+BrKzOy0Dei4UyGtCpM1tSw7YTi3Q6doO4-jIaTi493OzA+spQO0ao5ddUhTbGh21921OwtMCuyDF0ezdZVPQbqXG-LJwW8Fq2R6A9vfbdsdEwnIfgyjUPo7DODw0jEOownx2kDjMg83ir16AAtHoUYh+nQddiOorbLCRNLGq5oRwyhcsxN7YTF+ce1ldeMpyN4i+3Hj16AA-P44hRJg90AORRgA8v9cQn24fs76gehW08EorgBL4zVl0aXwdAMlBhyY0FTCAOceIeJ1h5CpTcVx1LOQoviXmxJB5+W-tEX+Y5ZIgEnOIacs5fDzmmJUJcK4zoQO9IWS424LIuX3O5Fex5USoDvJea8t5RL3hXE+d+YEPzWhAN+X8ylYL2TKigvKyEJIymmiCccckdAoD5IREIYQaCkDQOYKacAyxKUgRQmBmlcI6VAO3AyPkO6iLQSAcirl9I2VMQhcxcRYGuQPB5Py3lvRv3sVffKPoVrBl6hFXxA0QxBDiglIMht-7oB0GETKZI+HLwKgY-CJUZzelsh1AajU4BNFIpFYKhD-FpECWHEAABiR0lSV4BPPj0KAdAMn5KqpQaoDFjHenKqzSanYElEylivKM7iukLx6X7aYatEqRJkcAqkMEQABAyKEcIkJ1GTE0QRbSKTFEmkaUE3OwYmqZIKW1JiXomloBVkUvqRy8QpB0PNFEdheJtzXrzDprZulLz6cuSZqUokzNiQoxZyjVGoFWQiJJmzirbPSf1fZDQclWjhZCQpHpTksXOagS5YUSmdUsTQe5zgnltNefhTp892ZzTjuM96ETkrJSAA).

Is there a way I should manipulate the signal before I insert it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating another signal. I have updated the [spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-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-XttpqqAfYDv89aPH6D0eWiqQ012eZwC90y+LA0IU8jADUejyOkSBuFLMAywAjPLiu80gtx6Iz4lvTcSHxhpFrq2uG3tUSSXbRoGpwP9h1HaTCMwFjEO3QTRMQMuLgvW7a3G-KpslY5N13bFqJdDtjvO0srtk57kc+49jnvSbE5m8syslNHzX2xyTvs4DQce5dCNe+I0MY3DleIzgyNozDmMN4gp34zIAsEl9egALR6Amqeh9n4fLHOwqliUODu6VDB2kXu0lwdvYLYOIDlyZPfHj04iB2Tb16AA-P44hRJgL0AOQJgA8sDcRX245dH6gei23KeXLeg4oylcmJz3QHqReyEHZ-VLnRLmVx0Bb35oTdOhk94H3dkfU+0wAgX2vnfB+7gn56BfsjN+H8TZ7lgoBDUOdsFnRBmmLUmYaDZhABuAkg1iwij0o8Ksp4Ar1iClScc39Ir32oXEWhGZ0DLnEKudcvhNzTH6lISm+52F0SPFw4yLleFXnxCZB8t5UDfjfB+L8Ckfx7n-OQ4CyhUIwMgjYXSWEfIgCodEGhv5lTEV2gVTSKAxSBGCKEcIqJzCLTgLWHSHCDJGS+H6ai5lcQ7wapA+yvdhGuNEZotychHp+i8skpxiI0kVR4Vk68t5clhXyRFQpOD86bVGmkZKIAC6vHSqkTKYZIxIQKjoMIxUXibzJmaaqFlTJ2jonklKcVupwCaCxKZw0GnjToi0kAABiD0myTJjVSLfHoUA6CTOafUyg1Q+KJNALZSB68Vru1liZBMlTOY3JgWTaYWtsrdLoegXpmEQABAyIEmgpA0AhMmGE0yNFRl1VxEclpMy5lOgWVUAaAYKgrM2hrP0OyJroBSDoUmN47DUm7vAwWly179mgYMu5u5Pn5W+UwpkfyAUBLCMC4JoSqpQptP4+qoA4X1L9D1DF7V+p+kGqKuKWLEpNNWfiuAhL7AkvumS0ZVznlUo3uXd5P0um5R2EAA)

Comment: Please provide description to your answer.

Comment: Idea is to create two signals one that updates the domain and another to insert data on trigger. The one which is created to insert into data should be in form of array. In the spec that I posted, there are two signals : `detailDomain` and  `insertVal`. `detailDomain` updates the domain of scale and `insertVal` is used to insert tuple to data